# Is there a simple way to extract content from a webpage?

Tags: perl, parsing, scripting

Our build software generates a webpage when the build fails, and lists the users who've committed since the last build. I'd like to have a way to parse the page for members of my team. For example:

```
   Commit
              18e1bc67b7e3123987daf8c219a4fbe2003de4
              by <a href="/user/bob.dole/">bob.dole</a></b><pre>1112233- Description on header is not carried forward to BD doc after PCPROJBILL is ran<br></pre></div></td></tr><tr><td width="16"><img title="The file was modified" height="16" alt="The file was modified" width="16" src="/static/fbfd5d7f/images/16x16/document_edit.png" /></td><td><a>pcbatch/projbill.cpp</a></td></tr><tr class="pane"><td colspan="2" class="changeset"><a name="detail54"></a><div class="changeset-message"><b>
```

So the script would take a URL as input and search the file for 'bob.dole' and output to a file all of the details associated with him (commit hash, pre-data, etc.)

Could someone give me an idea of what would be the easiest way to accomplish this? I was thinking of using perl, but I'm not sure if there's something more straightforward.

Comment: So you want to get the webpage and parse it for bob.dole? Did I get your question correctly?

Comment: Yes, essentially - If I could just figure out how to get the web page into a stream of some kind, I think I could handle it from there. But if there are current tools out there that would let me search based on nodes (e.g., `<a href`, `<pre>`, etc.) that would be perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you question correctly, you want to get the webpage content and parse it to find the user name. If it is the case, I would use `php`

Use [**get_file_content**](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)("your_website"), this will return a string to you to parse.
Then you can use `strpos()` to find indeces of substrings. This will later help you to extract the user name by using `substr()` function.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Perl module you are looking for that helps you search based on nodes is [Mojo::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-4.16/lib/Mojo/DOM.pm).